# TSQL/Webforms: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0

Tags: t-sql, webforms

Im working in a webform creator program, with its own SQL database.
I have one table named "Prijs" and one column named "Prijseen". When writing a value to a particuler text field called "Offerte_totaalsom" I get this error:

"System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0."

The code I wrote is seen below:

DECLARE @TEST int

SET @TEST = '[field name='Offerte_totaalsom']'

INSERT INTO Prijs(Prijseen)
VALUES(@TEST)

The table in the database already has an index set and the value is also written into the table when inputting a value in the text field.

I already browsed for this error message but none of the solutions is specific to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The insert statement you are generating looks improperly formatted.

change the line

```
SET @TEST = '[field name='Offerte_totaalsom']'
```

to

```
SET @TEST = 'Offerte_totaalsom'
```

see what happens.

Comment: Another error message occurs because 'Offerte_totaalsom' is now seen as a string instead as a field name. The field name declaration is correct, it writes the input into the tabel as I want to, put nevertheless throws the exception.

Comment: the tql you have isn't correct, you would atleast need to escape the ' character to get this.

SET @TEST = '[field name=''Offerte_totaalsom'']'